# Chrome Headless Testing

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I want to use chromedriver headless instead of phantomjs. For phantomjs , I was able to provide the ssl certificate and key paths as commandline arguments. as below. How do I provide certificate and key paths as command line arguments for headless chromedriver?

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> commandLineArguments = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()                        
                                                                                .put("ssl-protocol", "any")                                                           
                                                                                .put("ssl-client-certificate-file", certificatePath)
                                                                                .put("ssl-client-key-file", certificateKeyPath)
                                                                                .put("ssl-client-key-passphrase", "webpass").build();

                                            String[] params = commandLineArguments.entrySet().stream()
                                                                .map(e -> String.format("--%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                                                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                                                .toArray(new String[0]);

                                            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                                            cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriver driver;
case WebDriverType.CHROME:
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    cOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                    cOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                    // this isthe option to run chrome in headless mode
                    cOptions.setHeadless(true);
                    cOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                    cOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
                    break;
```

You can pass this way as well to run chrome in headless mode.

Comment: How do i pass the certificate path and key file path? The website requires ssl certificate.

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors"); DesiredCapabilities crcapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); crcapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);